# How to style markers on .NET Chart axes

Tags: .net, styles, mschart, axes

I need to indicate points on the X and Y axes of a .NET Chart(class System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart) as hyphen-style markers. Right now the X and Y axes are completely plain.

Below is a picture of how I'd like to style my chart axes (screenshot taken from another charting tool):
[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: It's attached to my question. Can't you see it? I'm able to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. The key properties here are MajorTickMark and MinorTickMark.
eg.

```
chartAreaObject.AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = true;
chartAreaObject.AxisX.MajorTickMark.LineColor = Color.White;
```